# How to run read command inside a Dockerfile?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I have the following bash script command

```
read -r -d '' FILECONTENT <<'ENDFILECONTENT'
index index.html;

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

ENDFILECONTENT

echo "$FILECONTENT" > /etc/nginx/common.conf
```

**How do I change this so it will run successfully inside a Dockerfile?**

I have tried

```
## Common Configuration
run read -r -d '' FILECONTENT <<'ENDFILECONTENT'
index index.html;

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

ENDFILECONTENT

run echo "$FILECONTENT" > /etc/nginx/common.conf
```

I got the following error when I did `docker build -t ubuntu1404/djangoapp .`

```
Step 10 : RUN read -r -d '' FILECONTENT <<'ENDFILECONTENT'
 ---> Running in 69508c5aaed0
/bin/sh: 1: read: Illegal option -d
INFO[0062] The command [/bin/sh -c read -r -d '' FILECONTENT <<'ENDFILECONTENT'] returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Comment: Did you try to isolate it in a shell, and run that shell during `docker build`? Or to put that same shell in an entrypoint or cmd, and run it only on `docker run`?

Comment: I don't understand by isolate in a shell and run that shell during `docker build`. I also don't understand the 2nd suggestion. Can write it out?

Comment: Instead of putting a `RUN read ...` in the Dockerfile, try a `RUN readfile.sh, with `readfile.sh` including the `read` command.

Comment: The second suggestion is about the command run on a docker run of your image (see dockerfile entrypoint or cmd directives): it could be a script which builds the right config file, and then execute your service;

Comment: k10d at #docker irc suggested using COPY. It worked for me.

Comment: Good point. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

k10d in #docker irc channel suggested that I use COPY.

This worked

1. Have the following

   ```
   index index.html;
   location ~ /\.ht {
     deny all;
   }
   ```

inside `nginx_configuration/common.conf`

`nginx_configuration/` is a folder that is adjacent to Dockerfile

2. Type the following inside the Dockerfile

`## copy the nginx config files
     COPY ./nginx_configuration/common.conf /etc/nginx/common.conf`

3. Run the dockerfile as per normal.

   ```
   docker build -t ubuntu1404/djangoapp .
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I would do as VonC says: put that script in your repo and run it as an entrypoint at runtime so it generates your configuration before starting your service.